# largest group that fulfills a certain equality

Tags: group-theory

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group of degree $n$ and let $G,H$ be subgroups of $S_n$. Is there a way to find the largest group $G'$ such that $GH = G'H$? What can we say about $G'$?

In particular im interested in the case $H=S_{M_1}\times S_{M_2} \times ... \times S_{M_k} \subseteq S_n$ for $M_1 \sqcup M_2 \sqcup ... \sqcup M_k = \{1, 2, ..., n\}$.

Comment: Why do you think there should be a unique largest subgroup $G'$ with this property?

Comment: If $G'H=GH$ and $G''H=GH$ then also $\langle G', G''\rangle H = GH$.

Comment: why should $\langle G',G''\rangle\le GH$?

Comment: For $\sigma \in \langle G', G'' \rangle$ write $\sigma = \sigma_1' \sigma_1''...\sigma_k' \sigma_k''$ with $\sigma_1', ..., \sigma_k' \in G'$ and $\sigma_1'', ..., \sigma_k'' \in G''$. Since $G'H = GH = G''H$ we obtain $\sigma_k' \sigma_k'' H \subseteq \sigma_k' G''H = \sigma_k' G'H = G' H$. It follows inductively that $\sigma H \subseteq G H$ so $ \langle G', G'' \rangle H = GH$.

Comment: For the induction you seem to assume $GH$ is a group?

Comment: The next step would be to show that $\sigma_{k-1}' \sigma_{k-1}'' \sigma_k' \sigma_k'' H \subseteq GH$. Since $\sigma_k' \sigma_k'' H \subseteq G'H = G''H$ we obtain $\sigma_{k-1}' \sigma_{k-1}'' \sigma_k' \sigma_k'' H \subseteq \sigma_{k-1}' \sigma_{k-1}''  G''H = \sigma_{k-1}' G''H = \sigma_{k-1}' G'H = G'H = GH$.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your argument. So I guess the answer to the question is the largest such subgroup is $GL$ where $L$ is that the unique largest subgroup of $H$ such that $GL$ is a group or, equivalently, that $GL=LG$. But I don't know if that helps much!

Answer (score -1):

The largest subgroup $G'$ of $S_n$ for which $GH=G'H$ is just $GH$. Indeed, the equation $GH=GHH$ trivially holds, and if $K$ is another subgroup of $S_n$ for which $GH=KH$, then $K \leq KH=GH$ because $e \in H$.

Actually, the above argument would work for any group in place of $S_n$.

Comment: This assumes that $GH$ is actually a subgroup (which is not a given).

Comment: For example, take $n=3$, $G=\langle (1,2)\rangle$, $H=\langle (1,3)\rangle$. Then $GH$ is not a subgroup, and the largest subgroup of $S_n$ with the desired property is $G$ itself.

Comment: Another example where $G' \neq G$ and $G' \neq GH$ would be the following. Let $D_8$ be the dihedral group in $S_4$ containing $(1\; 3)$  and let $D_8'$ be the dihedral group in $S_4$ containing $(1\; 2)$. Then $D_8'$ is the largest group such that $(1\; 2) D_8 = D_8' D_8$.